# Digital Resident Evil 6 corrupted download on new console?

Tags: xbox-360, resident-evil-6

I bought a digital copy of resident evil 6 and played it on a console in a region.

Now I went to another region and tried downloading it again, but every time I come check the download (which I believe fully downloads because I have seen it reach +50%) I can't play it. Checking the storage shows me that the game is corrupted ... I tried this 3 times already and I keep getting a corrupted download.

What's the reason behind this ?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the corrupted data before re-downloading the game?

Comment: @Sean Yes I did, doesn't work.